# Console output to subprocess

Tags: c++, subprocess, console-output

I'm trying to send commands through the console output via std::cout to a command-line program that I started with fopen("foo.exe","w"). I want to wait until the process has finished before continuing executing my main application. For some reason this crashes my application. Is there a better way of starting the command-line program and sending console outputs?

Thanks a lot!

Nhat

Comment: You should read the standard library documentation before you try staring a process that way. Won't work. Moink!

Comment: `std::cout` is "character out", as opposed to `std::wcout` (which is "wide character out").  They both write to stdout.  Often, stdout is associated with a terminal.  There is nothing about a "console" here.  Do not conflate stdout with a terminal, and stop calling your terminal a "console".  Most terminals are not consoles.

Answer (score 0):

You need `popen()` and `pclose()`, not `fopen()` - hope you are speaking of Linux or any POSIX compliant OS.

See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-to-a-Subprocess.html) for example - you can find thousands of them.